# KeyError: 'image_url' Traceback (most recent call last) Error in response of flask api

Tags: python, flask, traceback

I have a React app to display an image & crop it. I am using flask api to post that image. When i ran my api in postman, it is working fine but on making request from react server(localhost:3000) to backend server(localhost:5000), it gives this response. My params includes a json with sole param of image_url. What do i do to resolve this issue. Please Help. Thank you, If any code is needed apart from this i will post it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ets/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ets/Desktop/pwaProcessRetina/ReactFlaskpwa/mysql.py", line 26, in signUp
    image_url = request.get_json()['image_url']
KeyError: 'image_url'
```

Comment: have you checked what response is coming from request.get_json() function? It may happen that the response doesn't contain the key 'image_url'.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMasudTushar How do i check it? I am new to python & print doesn't doent work

Comment: if you are using IDE like pycharm to develop the app, you can try out with debugger and give a breakpoint to the line from where the error is coming. With debugger you can see what is in the response. You can take help from google about the debugger if you are new on it :)

Comment: Thank you. This is the Result {'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'params': {'image_url': 'blob:http://localhost:3000/657b3055-291d-4f19-a5e2-e88b1d3eca49'}}

Answer (score 0):

> Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using
>   the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.

[KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) in your case means that the key `image_url` doesn't exist in the dict. Print out the JSON and verify it.

Comment: Sorry to ask such trivial question but how do i print json i get from react?

Comment: In your `mysql.py` add this line `print(request.get_json())` before the `image_url = request.get_json()['image_url']`. Or if you have enabled the Werkzeug Debugger (using `export FLASK_DEBUG=1`), you can access the debugger console in the frontend and access the objects.

Comment: this is print result ==>  {'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'params': {'image_url': 'blob:http://localhost:3000/657b3055-291d-4f19-a5e2-e88b1d3eca49'}}

Comment: Replace `request.get_json()['image_url']` with `request.get_json()['params']['image_url']`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. So i have to give the full structure of my request param?

Comment: It works because that's how you access the nested key's value of a dictionary. Perhaps visualizing the dictionary might show you the nested structure. For example - https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier/cb945bf9.